# Log soap request and response using apache-cxf

Tags: cxf

I am working on Maven project in Intellij.I have generated wsdl to java using cxf-codegen-plugin. I have created a client and created a tester.java to test the client. I have to log the soap request and response. I have one cxf.xml, config.properties and a client.java files. I am not sure where to configure to log the soap messages. Also i have less idea about webservices. I have also copied log4j.xml to my METAINF.

I have tried all possible scenarios in stack overflow. Not sure which is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the latest version of CXF (or fairly recent), the easiest way is to enable the logging feature on the CXF bus in the cxf.xml:

```
...
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
...
```

or only on your jaxws endpoint:

```
<jaxws:endpoint...>
  <jaxws:features>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature"/>
  </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Make sure you have `cxf-rt-features-logging-XXX.jar` on your classpath (XXX = your version of CXF).

And configure logging as described here:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html

You need to be in INFO level at least.

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you.